# Aligning text inside rectangle of html5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, text-align

I have resizable rectangle, and I wish to have right-aligned text (day numbers) next to it.

what I have now:

[image: what I have now]

(also when resizing the text does not really align vertically)

what I wish to have:

[image: what I wish to have]

Is there a way to fill the text and align it inside a drawn rectangle? Other suggestions are welcome too.

[js.do code](https://js.do/jsdoremi/278607)

```
        function dayRect(day) {
            const days = ["I","II","III","IV","V","VI","VII"];
            context.beginPath();

            //maybe align the text inside this rect somehow
            context.rect(0, day*h/7, 3*w/27, h/7);

            context.stroke();
            context.font = "0.5rem Arial";
            context.fillStyle = "#fff";
            context.fillText(days[day], 0, (day+1)*h/7);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I've changed a few things in your code since I wasn't able to see anything. You need to use `context.textAlign="right"` for your text and move it to a different position. I hope it helps.

```js
  function getMousePos(canvas, evt) {
   var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
   return {
   x: evt.clientX - rect.left,
   y: evt.clientY - rect.top
   };
  }
  
  var canvas = document.getElementById("posHourCanvas");
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    canvas.width=600,canvas.height=300;
  
  var boxes = [];
  
  function init() {
   context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
   boxes.length = 0;
   const strokeWidth = 0.6;
   //canvas.width = $('#two')[0].clientWidth;
   var cellSize = canvas.width/27;
   canvas.height = 7/27 * canvas.width;
   var x = y = 0;
   draw(x,y,canvas.width,canvas.height,cellSize,strokeWidth);
  }
  
  function Box(x, y, day, hour) {
   this.x = x;
   this.y = y;
   this.day = day;
   this.hour = hour;
  }
  
  function draw(x, y, w, h, cellSize, strokeWidth) {
  
   let onePixel = cellSize * strokeWidth;
   cellSize = cellSize * (1 - strokeWidth);
   context.beginPath();
   context.lineWidth = 1;
   context.strokeStyle = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)';
   const rectCoordinates = {
    x: x+3*w/27,
    y: y,
    w: w-3*w/27,
    h: h
   }
   context.rect(rectCoordinates.x, y, rectCoordinates.w, h);
   context.fillStyle = 'white';
   context.fill();
   context.stroke();
   
   let offX = rectCoordinates.w/24 + rectCoordinates.x;
   let offY = h/7;
   
   for (let i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    dayRect(i);
    context.beginPath();    
    context.moveTo(0, offY);
    context.lineTo(w, offY);
    context.strokeStyle = "black";
    context.stroke();
    offY+=h/7;
   }
   
   for (let i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(offX, 0);
    context.lineTo(offX, h);
    context.stroke();
    offX+=rectCoordinates.w/24;
   }
   
   function dayRect(day) {
    const days = ["I","II","III","IV","V","VI","VII"];
    context.beginPath();

    context.rect(0, day*h/7, 3*w/27, h/7);
    
    context.stroke();
    context.font = "0.5rem Arial";
    context.fillStyle = "#fff";
        context.textAlign="right";
    context.fillText(days[day], 60, (day+1)*h/7);
   }   
  }
 
  init();
```

```css
body {
  margin: auto;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div>text above</div>

  <div id="two">
    <canvas id="posHourCanvas" width="600" height="300"></canvas>
  </div>

  <div>text under</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you mean it was too small for you to see? There's a "fullscreen" function on js.do, it should be visible then. I don't quite understand where to exactly context.textAlign aligns? I see you've commented out "//canvas.width = $('#two')[0].clientWidth;", the problem is, that the canvas is no more resizable after that. Is there a way to leave it resizable and have the alignment you've added. As for <canvas id="posHourCanvas" width="600" height="300"> - these numbers may be changed.